# Unable to discover bluetooth peripheral or service from iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I am attempting to scan for a bluetooth device using the CoreBluetooth framework. The device is a prototype provided by a client.

I believe my implementation of the `CBCentralManagerDelegate` is correct, but I am never receiving the `centralManager: didDiscoverPeripheral: advertisementData: RSSI:` callback. Even if I register for `nil` service UUIDs, which should fire discovery callbacks for all devices, nothing happens.

I would consider whether the bluetooth device might be defective, except here's the wrinkle... when I fire up the Bluetooth debugging application LightBlue on my iPad, the prototype device is listed, along with some services. In fact, as soon as I use that app's 'clone' feature to reproduce the service from the iPad directly, my delegate callback fires.

I can post some sample code but it really is boiler plate stuff (I believe). Bluetooth experts: are there any obvious causes for the behavior I am experiencing?

Comment: A few lines of code would be interesting. Did you check the `CBCentralManager` before scanning?

Comment: Thanks, I will add something shortly. Check it for what?

Comment: For example, if `[yourCentralManager state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff`, you won't be able to scan...

Answer (score 0):

Some points to check: make sure you have set the delegate of your CCBCentralManager correctly. If your device is bonded to iOS device I suppose `didDiscoverPeripheral`should not be fired, but in this case LightBlue app would not show any service at "Scanning for peripherals..." screen.

Good luck